# There is no row at position 0

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net, exception

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from product where prod_code='" & Trim(txtprod_code.Text) & "' and branch='" & w_location & "' and avail_stock <>" & (0) & ""
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
con.Open()
da_uqc.SelectCommand = cmd
cmd.Connection = con
da_uqc.Fill(ds_uqc)
m_qty = ds_uqc.Tables(0).Rows(0)(4) 'error 
da_uqc.Dispose()
ds_uqc.Dispose()
cmd.Dispose()
```

Is it possible to give like this `m_qty = ds_uqc.Tables(0).Rows(0)(4)`?

Comment: isn't vb a 1-based language? it's been years since I used it so can't remember for sure.

Comment: @vignesh:Make sure your quesry returning result

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx:in vb arrays were 1-based but in vb.net 0-based  :)

Answer (score 5):

You're getting a run-time error denoting that there was no rows at all in the table since your query string does not get any matching rows, you may check rows count first:

```
If ds_uqc.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 then
    m_qty = ds_uqc.Tables(0).Rows(0)(4)
End If
```

**P.S:** comments in VB.Net, starts by `'` and not the C#.Net one `//`.

Comment: m_qty Hear i am getting quantity from data base and assigning that value to that variable

Answer (score 2):

That tells you that no rows were loaded, presumably because there was no matching product/etc. This could be a case-sensitivity issue, or there could genuinely be no such products.

For info, using concatenation of inputs ***IS BAD***. You should always prefer a parameterised command, both to avoid data-errors (when you get a quote in a name) but more importantly to avoid SQL injection.