# I need help in C# in Visual Studio, when I run the app it gives me there is no row at position 0

Tags: c#

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{  
    if (e.RowIndex >=0) 
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        int a = int.Parse(row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());
        i.TrenutniID = a;     
    }                    
}
```

in other form

```
int trenutniID;

public int TrenutniID
{
    get
    {
        return trenutniID;
    }

    set
    {
        trenutniID = value;
    }
}
private void IzmjeniOsobu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("potrebni id je : "+ trenutniID);
    string queryStr = "SELECT * from abba.osoba where ID=" + trenutniID + ";";
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, conDataBase);

    try
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
        DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dbdataset);

        var stringArr = dbdataset.Rows[0].ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();

        idField.Text = stringArr[0];
        oib.Text = stringArr[1];
        name.Text = stringArr[2];
        lastname.Text = stringArr[3];
        place.Text = stringArr[4];
        adress.Text = stringArr[5];
        no.Text = stringArr[6];
        mail.Text = stringArr[7];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I want to do update, from grid to take the data, and when I click button update, to give me the form of update and that are fill with data so i can update.

Comment: I am assuming your error is at `dbdataset.Rows[0].ItemArray`. When you run the actual query against MySql do you get any rows back? Your error is because you are accessing row[0] without checking if you have any rows returned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no row at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556171/there-is-no-row-at-position-0)

Comment: Run the query without the where is verify if  you have the correct trenutniID.  Then check if the ID you are using is in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution this may help

Updated Code:

```
MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
        DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dbdataset);
if(dbdataset.Rows.Count>0)
{
        var stringArr = dbdataset.Rows[0].ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();

        idField.Text = stringArr[0];
        oib.Text = stringArr[1];
        name.Text = stringArr[2];
        lastname.Text = stringArr[3];
        place.Text = stringArr[4];
        adress.Text = stringArr[5];
        no.Text = stringArr[6];
        mail.Text = stringArr[7];
}
else
{
//Do somthing
}
```

Comment: Thanks now is not showing there is no row at position 0, but Its now showing me my datas from datagrid, when I click on datagrid then on button Update, its opening it without errors, but fileds are empty..

Comment: Make sure that the sql query is correct and you have data in table

Comment: sql query is okay, but my setter and getters are not wokring

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL query returned no rows (there is no abba.osoba with an ID of `<whatever trenutniID is>`)

```
SELECT * from abba.osoba where ID=" + trenutniID + ";
```

Perhaps some defensive coding, and a bit of a tidy up:

```
    string queryStr = "SELECT * from abba.osoba where ID=@id";
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, conDataBase);

    //important! do not concatenate values into SQL strings. Put a parameter then populate it with a value
    cmdDAtaBase.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32 ).Value = trenutniID;

    try
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        if(dt.Rows.Count ==0)
          MessageBox.Show("Unknown ID " + trenutniID);
        else{

          idField.Text = dt.Rows[0]["id"].ToString(); //you could use a "string" name of column here instead of numbers like 0. it's marginally easier to read
          oib.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString(); //or "oib" etc? 
          name.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
          lastname.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
          place.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
          adress.Text = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
          no.Text = dt.Rows[0][6].ToString();
          mail.Text = dt.Rows[0][7].ToString();
       }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

This would also get significantly easier if you'd use data binding, but you haven't posted enough info to make a recommendation on that

Comment: query is working, I don't have anything In my db with ID 0 but when I change ID in code than it works, getter returns 0 so it cannot work I think

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you enter data into datagrid and not hit Enter. In order to add a row in datagrid you have to hit enter before calling the update function you've written.

Please add the following to your function before 'try':

If (dbdataset.Rows.Count() == 0)
{
       //Show some message informing the user to enter data first and make sure to hit Enter button
       return;
}